# Regular expression over $\{a, b\}$ for all words with an even number of $a$s, but without consecutive $a$s

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, automata, regular-expressions

I was given the following problem.

> **Problem.** Give a regular expression over $\{a, b\}$ whose language is the set of all words with an even number of $a$s, but without consecutive $a$s. For example, $bbaba$ is in the language, but $bbaab$ is not.

My approach was to build an automaton with four states:

- $A$: even number of $a$s and last input was $a$.
- $B$: even number of $a$s and last input was not $a$.
- $C$: odd number of $a$s and last input was $a$.
- $D$: odd number of $a$s and last input was not $a$.

The final states are $A$ and $B$ where $a$ is even.

I skip the drawing of this automaton. Suffice it to says it is an automaton that accepts the language I am required to express. Using Kleene's algorithm I found the language of the automaton is $(b+ab^{+}ab)^{*} (b^{*} + ab^{+}a + ab^{+}ab)$. This seems to make sense. Consider this regular expression in parts.

$$
(b+ab^{+}ab)^{*}
$$

is the set of chains with even number of $a$s and no consecutive $a$s that end in $b$. This includes $b$ itself with zero $a$s, because zero is even. For example, $b, babab, babbb\ldots ab$, arre all chains in this language.

To this language, any indefinite number of $b$s may follow, and hence we may append $b^{*}$ to it. Alternatively, the expression $ab^{+}a$ may follow, making the whole chain with $a$ but holding the even number of $a$s and no consecutive $a$s. Lastly, any chain of the form $ab^{+}ab$ may also follow, adding a chain that ends with $b$. Hence, the set of things that can be appended is

$$
(b^{*} + ab^{+}a+ab^{+}ab)
$$

In short, the regular expression seems to satisfy the condition.

My question is: is there some shorter or simpler approach other than building an automaton and using Kleene's algorithm? I did try to build the regular expression by intuition before this more systematic approach, but failed, and uppon finding the expression I do acknowledge that is not so trivial that it can be guessed or quickly built.

Comment: You say "any number of $ab^+a$ chains may follow, but this is not true, nor is it what your regex says. Only one chain of that form may follow, which is what your regex says as well.

Also, I don't see why you need to the $ab^+ab$ term in the second factor. That would be covered the first factor ending with an $ab^+ab$ and the second factor being the empty string, which is an option due to $b^*$. Or am I missing something?

Comment: I corrected the error, the claim was that the subchain $ab^{+}a$ may follow, but not an indefinite number of such subchain. Thanks for pointing it out. I think you are right in the redundancy of $ab^{+}ab$ in the second factor. However, I don't really care about the regex being as concise as possible as much as I care for the fact that it generates the correct language